# How do I get value of MUI Autocomplete componet using FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to submit values in React JS application using FormData but, I have an issue with Autocomplete component.

This component has value "4" for "US Dollars" option, but FormData gives me selected text instead of selected value.

```
const fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('frmMain'));
    var formDataObject = Object.fromEntries(fd.entries());
    console.log(fd);
```

[image]
I tried all the methods for FormData but there is nothing to get value of selected Item or such